# Passing Data from a UITableView to a UIViewController (Detailview)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cocoa

I am trying to pass data  from a tableview (integrated in a normal view controller) to a detail view. I have done this several times already, but always relied on a `TableViewController`. Now it is the first time I am using a `UITableView` within a normal `UIViewController`. And somehow I cannot manage to get the `prepareforseque` method to execute.

Here is some part of my code:

```
-(void)preparForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
         NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.GTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
         GDetails *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
         destViewController.GName = [[JSONGRListe objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]    
                 objectForKey:@"gname"]}}
```

What I have checked so far:

1. I have a push segue that is called "ShowDetails". And the animation shows up. However no data is passed.
2. The detail view's class I want to push data to is selected as GDetails in IB.
3. The JSON Data is accessible. I have tested it with NSLog.
4. In GDetails.h I have declared

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *GDetails;
   ```

   and the NSString is synthesized in GDetails.m
5. I have imported GDetails.h in my View with the UITableView
6. I have created the GTableView with

   ```
   IBOutlet UITableView *GTableView;
   ```

   and synthesized it accordingly in my View with the UITableView.

So where am I messing it up. Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: I found my mistake :D I spelled it wrong and missed an "e"